# I can not boot my LiveCD OS with Ventoy

Tags: linux, boot, livecd, ventoy

I made a bootable USB stick with Ventoy tool. My USB stick is a Kingston 256GB usb-c DataTraveler Max. I created an about 38GB Partition for Ventoy tool. The remaining space I use for a separated fat32 data partition. I copied Ubuntu, Debian and Clonezilla livecd ISOs to the USB stick and tried to boot the USB stick. But none of the ISO files on the USB stick I can boot. When I install Ventoy on my Verbatim USB stick and copy the same ISO files to the Verbatim USB stick, than I can boot the ISO LiveCDs from this USB stick. So I know my laptop can use Ventoy to boot LiveCDs. **Why can I not boot LiveCDs from my Kingston 256GB USB stick?**

Comment: ventoy uses two partitions - usually the main partition first (with your images) and a 32MB boot partition - so, does your Kingston have THREE partitions seeing as you need two for Ventoy and then your fat32?

Comment: also, which partition are you adding your ISO to? the ventoy one or your reserved one

Comment: Ventoy is supposed to make a bootable USB all by itself right? Once it's finished making your USB drive bootable (and before you have written anything else to the drive) does it actually boot then? If not, ventoy has a problem - or maybe the USB drive has a problem

Comment: I created a bootable USB stick with an other program from the ISO and then tried to   boot my laptop with it. But I was not able to boot my laptop with it. Thus there is something wrong with the combination of laptop and USB stick. Is my laptop to old for this modern USB stick? I saw that my last bios update was in 2018 and there is no more recent update available for my laptop. Why does one USB stick can boot my laptop and an other can not? Is it likely when I buy an other recent USB stick of a other vendor, this USB stick is also not able to boot my laptop?